# Spring Boot: How to initialize a class of constant values

Tags: java, spring

I'm putting constant values of spring boot my application in a final class:

```
public final class SecurityConstants {
    /*
     * Authentication will only be initiated for the requests with matching URLs
     */
    protected final static String DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESS_URL = "/mypath/**";

    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    public static final String BEARER = "Bearer";

    public static final String JWT_SECRET = System.getenv("JWT_SECRET_KEY");

    public static final long EXPIRATIONTIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days

}
```

The problem is that when I access the `JWT_SECRET` value it's null, because the class is not loaded. I don't think it makes sense to annotate this class with `@Component`. I'm wondering how I should load the class and initialize these constants.

Comment: Looks to me like the best practice for this use case would be to use a [property file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: I do not think that the class is not loaded.

Comment: @Jens I debug the code and the constructor isn't called.

Comment: @anothernode I'd like to get values of some constants from the system environment variables.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh You have only static properties!! Why you expect a constructor call?

Comment: why the value for that static field is not instantiated then ?

Comment: Try reading some other system variable. May be your system variables are not updated and JWT_SECRET_KEY is not visible.

Comment: @S.K. I think the problem is that eclipse doesn't pickup the value from the environment value. I set the value in the terminal, and I can see the value in `printenv` and I run eclipse on the same terminal windows, but eclipse ignores the value.

Comment: I'd like to mention that I restart eclipse and it recognizes other environment variables, but doesn't recognize the one I added.

Comment: It might be related to this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490816

Comment: You can add environment variables in eclipse run configuration for testing through eclipse.

Comment: `System.getenv` doesn't require any custom classes to be loaded or their constructor being called. It only reqiures the environment variable to be actually present in your process.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class as bean set the initial values to it. So that you can access it across the application.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the constants are static, you can access them using the Class name.
For your case, to access JWT_SECRET you can write - SecurityConstants.JWT_SECRET